# Why does 6.00 + (plus) 5.00 = "5.006.00"?

Tags: javascript, numbers

If I have a variable that is given a "numeric" value from a PHP `echo`...

```
var names_each = <?php echo $ind_name_each; ?>;
```

...and `$ind_name_each` is derived from a MySQL column of type `decimal(5,2)`,
is it a number or a string in JavaScript?

if all_total = 6.00
and names_each = 5.00
and I do this:

```
all_total = parseInt(names_each) + all_total;
```

I get 56.00

```
all_total = names_each + all_total;
```

I get 5.006.00

```
all_total = parseFloat(names_each) + all_total;
```

I get 56.00

I need some understanding here.

Comment: What happens if you set `all_total = parseFloat(names_each) + parseFloat(all_total)` it looks like all_total may be a string which is why it is doing a string concat

Comment: If you want to perform addition, **both** operands have to be numbers. Otherwise string concatenation is performed. And unless `$ind_name_each` contains a string with quotes, such as `'"5"'`, `names_each` will already be a number.

Comment: BTW: only `all_total = '6.00'` and `names_each = '5.00'` will give you these results

Comment: this question is ***related*** to PHP and not Javascript... please re-tag it...

Comment: @JZ - when i float the all_total, it works.. Thanks... I set all_total=0; as a global. is that a number or string?  i then have code that operates on it and from everything i can tell it is returning a number.. 6.00 you can see it here firstlove.com form on the left takes you to second page where calc is done.

Comment: There is no reason that names_each should be a string based off of your first bit of code. Is other code modifying names_each after declaration and before all_total = names_each + all_total; ?

Comment: *is that a number or string?*: Strings literas are denoted by quotation marks `"` or `'`. You really should have a look at the basics of JavaScript in the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals).

Comment: Such a question is the basis of [the jQuery meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492). ([The original 2010 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603) (now deleted - only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both variables are strings:

```
var names_each = '5.0', all_total = '6.0';
```

so the + operation concatenates those strings:

```
console.log(names_each + all_total);  // '5.0' + '6.0' => '5.06.0'
console.log(parseInt(names_each) + all_total); // 5 + '6.0' => '5' + '6.0' => '56.0'
```

but if you parse them to numbers first, then you can use + to add them:

```
all_total = parseInt(names_each) + parseInt(all_total);
console.log(all_total);  // 5 + 6 => 11
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert `all_total` from string to int / float too...

Because now, `+` in all three examples is string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, if *either* side of the `+` operator is a string value then *both* sides are converted to a string and the result of the operator is the string concatenation of those values. Here are some examples:

```
 1  +  2   // 3
"1" + "2"  // "12"
"1" +  2   // "12"
 1  + "2"  // "12"
```

Note that the last 3 cases have the *same* result.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

On your examples it's not clear where `all_total` comes from in the first place, but it must be a string, since you are getting string concatenation instead of addition.

To answer your first question, **`names_each` is not a string, it's a number**.

The output of this PHP file

```
var names_each = <?php echo $ind_name_each; ?>;
```

Should be something like this:

```
var names_each = 5;
```

or

```
var names_each = 5.1;
```

So, it's not a string, but an actual number in js. If the other side of your attempted addition is a string, you get string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are strings, not numbers.
Therefore, unless you explicitly convert them to numbers, you get string concatenation.

Comment: He is using `parseInt(names_each)` in the first example which should convert it to an int, yet he still gets string concat

Answer (score 1):

The following will tell you what they are:

```
console.log(typeof names_each);
console.log(typeof all_total);
```

Here are some examples:

```
typeof "6.00" // The result is "string"
typeof 6.00 // The result is "number"
```

If you add some logging to your application, you should be able to see where it is turning into a string.

Also, you should know that the following occurs:

```
5.00 == "5.00" // The result is "true"
5.00 === "5.00" // The result is "false"
```

Using the triple equals prevents the JavaScript engine from implicitly casting the type of your variable. So, with === you will get a strict comparison with no auto-type casting.