# JavaScript function to add two numbers is not working right

Tags: javascript, html, function

My code in HTML takes a user input number in, and it does a calculation and then displays the output. The user chosen input is put into a formula and the result of the formula is added to the user input number, but when it adds the two number together it's adding a decimal spot.

For example, if the number 11 is chosen, the result of Rchange is 0.22, so .22 is then added 11 to be 11.22  for newResistance, but instead it is displaying the value as 110.22 instead.

```
function calc(form) {
    if (isNaN(form.resistance.value)) {
        alert("Error in input");
        return false;
    }
    if (form.resistance.value.length > 32) {
        alert("Error in input");
        return false;
    }
    var Rchange = .01 * 2 * form.resistance.value;
    var newResistance = (form.resistance.value + Rchange);
    document.getElementById("newResistance").innerHTML = chopTo4(newResistance);
}

function chopTo4(raw) {
    strRaw = raw.toString();
    if (strRaw.length - strRaw.indexOf("0") > 4) strRaw = strRaw.substring(0, strRaw.indexOf("0") + 5);
    return strRaw;
}
```

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743145/why-does-6-00-plus-5-00-5-006-00.

Comment: seems to work ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/3WnNf/1/
so the problem must be within your `form.resistance.value`

Comment: Such a question is the basis of [the jQuery meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492). ([Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603) (now deleted - only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML DOM element properties are always strings. You need to convert them to numbers in your usage.

```
parseInt(form.resistance.value);
parseFloat(form.resistance.value);
+form.resistance.value;
```

(Any of the three will work; I prefer the first two (use parseInt unless you're looking for a float).)

Answer (score 0):

Try `newResistance = +form.resistance.value + Rchange;`. This will convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's treating the values as a string.

form.resistance.value + Rchange are both strings, so it's appending it.

Use the parseInt JavaScript method to get the decimal version.