# Add two numbers in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript. Our teacher asked us to write a program to add two numbers using function add(). The question is shown as follows.

However, when I use my code to add the two numbers. The result is not a number.

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  num1 = parseInt(x);
  num2 = parseInt(y);
  return (num1 + num2);
}

var input1 = window.prompt("Enter a number: ", 0);
var input2 = window.prompt("Enter another number: ", 0);
var input3 = window.prompt("Enter another number: ", 0);
var value1 = parseFloat(input1 + input2);
var value3 = parseFloat(input3);
var sum = sum(value1 + value3);

document.writeln("<h1> First number: " + value1 + "</h1>");
document.writeln("<h1> Second number: " + value3 + "</h1>");
document.writeln("<h1> Sum: " + sum + "</h1>");
```

Why the sum is not a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function to add two numbers not working right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565569/javascript-function-to-add-two-numbers-not-working-right)

Comment: var sum = sum(value1, value3); and apart from that, some other mistakes, parseFloat is wrong too as you're retrieving a string.

Comment: @AKA: You don't have to notify the OP with a comment that you posted an answer.  The same notification system also alerts them of answers in the first place.

Comment: Such a question is the basis of [the jQuery meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492). ([Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603) (now deleted - only visible to users with more than 10,000 reputation points).)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `parseFloat()` separately for `input1` and `input2` when you calculate the sum for `value1`. Another change is the `var sum = sum1(value1 , value3);` instead of `var sum = sum1(value1 + value3);` which makes the parameter `y` of `sum(x,y)` as `undefined`.

```js
var input1 = window.prompt("Enter a number: ", 0);
var input2 = window.prompt("Enter another number: ", 0);
var input3 = window.prompt("Enter another number: ", 0);
var value1 = parseFloat(input1) + parseFloat(input2);
var value3 = parseFloat(input3);
var sum = sum1(value1 , value3);
document.writeln("<h1> First number: " + value1 + "</h1>");
document.writeln("<h1> Second number: " + value3 + "</h1>");
 document.writeln("<h1> Sum: " + sum + "</h1>");

function sum1 (x,y)
{ 
   return (x+y);
}
```

Also, as `Adriani6` mentioned **you don't need to `parseFloat` again inside sum1 as you assign a parsed float already to `value1` and `value3`**

Comment: don't forget to remove the `debugger` line

Comment: Thanks @assembler for noticing that.

Comment: Should also be noted that you don't need to parseFloat again inside sum1 as you assign a parsed float already to value1 and value3.

Comment: Thaks @Adriani6 i included your comment in the answer. Thanks for improving

Comment: I appreciate that pick @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit dirty, this works:

```
var amount = 58.02;
var total = '&pound;' + (amount*1 + 177);
```

...gives the the expected answer of £217.73

Enclosing within brackets forces 'amount' to be a number. However...

```
var amount = 40.73;
var total = '&pound;' + (amount*1 + 177.82);
```

gives a really silly answer of £218.54999999999998 (!)

[ Edited 26th January - following part in *italics* kept for reference...

*This is only true if the (correct) decimal part of the answer is .55 or .65  Bug in Javascript???? (It's the same in Firefox and Chrome.)*

*So some more manipulation is required to be absolutely certain: multiplication, integerising and subsequent division by 100...*

```
var amount = 40.73;
document.write('Total is: &pound;' + parseInt(amount*100 + 17782) / 100);
```

*.. gives the correct answer of  'Total is: £218.55'* ]

**Edit:** Better solution found later uses toFixed() :-

```
var amount = 40.73;
var total = 'Total is: &pound;' + (amount* + 177.82).toFixed(2);
```

.. also gives the correct answer of  'Total is: £218.55'

Soooooo -

1) You need to enclose the numbers you want to add within brackets if the sum will be part of a string;

2) Multiplying each 'number' by one forces the result to be a number - so (input1*1 + input2*1) **is forced** to be the arithmetic sum.  This is necessary in the original questioner's script, but multiplying by one isn't needed in my example;

3) To ensure you don't get a silly answer, append .toFixed(n) to the bracketed expression - where n is the number of decimal places.

Utterly tedious (still)....

(and) Much better to use PHP if you can!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is here:

```
sum(value1 + value3)
```

Your `sum` function expects the arguments separately and will internally perform the addition, but you're adding them in-line before sending them to the function.  Since only one value is sent to `sum()`, its second argument is `undefined` and therefore "not a number".  Simply separate the values:

```
sum(value1, value3)
```

The *other* error that you may not have noticed yet is here:

```
parseFloat(input1 + input2)
```

If you enter `1` and `2` for example, the result of this will be `12`.  This is because you're "adding" (concatenating) the strings *before* converting them to a numeric value.  Convert them first, then add them.  Something like this:

```
var value1 = parseFloat(input1) + parseFloat(input2);
```

Aside from that the code can probably be cleaned up a bit more, such as not needing all of the parsing you're doing.  (Once something is parsed to a numeric value, it doesn't need to be parsed to a numeric value again.)  You'd also do well to look into setting values to elements on the page instead of using things like `document.writeln()`, but that could be a lesson for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Javascript, the + operator is overloaded, i.e., has multiple meanings depending on the arguments you give it. The + means concatenation for strings and addition for "numbers" (for different types of numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an add function that *takes* and *ads* as many parameters as you need:

```js
function add() {
  // Create an array from the functions arguments object
  // then sum the array members using reduce
  var sum = Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  console.log(sum);
}
// You can now add as many numbers as you like
// just by passing them to the function
add(2, 5);
add(2, 3, 5);
```